# How to connect nodejs client to mqtt broker

Tags: javascript, node.js, mqtt

How do I connect my mqtt client on nodejs to a mqtt broker which runs on a VM?
In this example, once the client connects, it should trigger the "Connected" log, but it doesn't print this.

```
var mqtt = require("mqtt");
var http = require("http");
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

var client = mqtt.connect("mqtt://192.168.56.2:1883");


client.on("connect", function () {
    client.subscribe("testTopic");
    console.log("connected");
});

client.on("message", function (topic, message) {
    // message is Buffer 
    console.log(message.toString());
    //client.end();
});
```

Comment: The code you've posted works fine, are you sure the broker is running and that there is no firewall on the VM?

Comment: works just fine when I'm using the java client.